# CC Payment method's form not loading in magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

One of our site is running on Magento-1.7, on Checkout page's payment method section credit card payment method is showing but it's form is not coming.

`getPaymentMethodFormHtml() returning "string(0)"`, respective function `$this->getChildHtml('payment.method.' . $method->getCode())` not returning required phtml file content.

Please suggest what can be the reason for this.

Thanks

Comment: @kunj any suggestion ?

Comment: is there any custom module related to it?

Comment: yes, IWD's one page checkout